# Why Huawei Honer mobile dosen't save the messsage sent by non-default sms application

Tags: android, sms

### Question description

I'm working on a sms application, and I've found something strange in sending message test.

My test mobile phones are these: an oneplue5(Android 8.0), a Meizu mobile(I forgot the specific model, Android 4.4), a Huawei Honer(the same to Meizu, Android 7.1). After sending the message, oneplue5 has saved record successfully in its default sms application even if my application isn't the default app, Meizu mobile make the same performence, Huawei Honer dosen't save the message in smd db.

So I've tried set my application as default sms application, and Huawei Honer saved the message in the sms db. I can't make my app as default app because of this way vetoed by my leader, is there any way to send a message successfully in my app in Huawei mobile without being default sms app?

Comment: Please add some of your code so other can help you. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "Only Huawei has shown the right performence" – Actually, you've got that backwards. Since 4.4, if your app is not the default messaging app, the system should automatically save any SMS it sends. It seems like Huawei has changed the standard behavior. You are correct that a non-default app shouldn't be able to write to the Provider, so I'm not sure that you could do anything, in that case. However, if they've changed that, they might also have changed the write restrictions, too, but you'd have to test that. Also, they might not even be using the standard SMS Provider model to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for point my mistake Mike M. Actually I've tried set my application as default, and at this scene Huawei Honer saved the message, maybe I need edit my description